# Globally adjust table borders

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010

I have a very large Word document with 100's of tables, where all borders need to be at 1 pt width.

How do I make this happen for all existing tables?

Comment: If all the tables are the same, then make the first table its own Style, adjust the borders, save the new style and then apply this Style to the other tables. I am not sure if you can select multiple tables and apply, but try.

Answer (score 1):

in order to leave all other table attributes in place, except the border width,
a VBA macro is the best solution, which is certainly is easier than manually
changing every table in the document.

The following macro, FixCellBorders, steps through every cell in every table in the
document and sets the minimum line weight to one point:

```
Sub FixCellBorders()
    ' Work through all tables in document
    For Each objTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        ' Work through all cells in each table
        For Each objCell In objTable.Range.Cells
            ' Work through all borders in each cell
            For Each objBorder In objCell.Borders
                ' set line weight to 1.00 point
                objBorder.LineWidth = wdLineWidth100pt
            Next objBorder
        Next objCell
    Next objTable
End Sub
```

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor.
Right-click "ThisWorkbook" and select *Insert > Module*.
Copy-paste the above text inside the editor.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the spreadsheet, and then
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close the VBA editor and return to Excel.

You may from now on go to the *Developer* pane, click on *Macros* which
will display the defined macros, select FixCellBorders and click *Run*.

For more detail see:

- [Setting a Default Table Border Width](https://word.tips.net/T000880_Setting_a_Default_Table_Border_Width.html)
- [WdLineWidth enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdlinewidth)